# postGIS tiger geocoder: tiger schema column definitions?

Tags: postgis

I'm using postGIS to deal with some geographic needs of our data system.  postGIS has some extras to allow easy loading of TIGER census data, and automatic creation of a `tiger` schema.  It seems that all of this is very strongly motivated by geocoding/reverse-geocoding addresses to lat-longs.  I actually don't need the geocoding service, but I DO want to fk the rest of my database to various geo-political structures in TIGER (e.g. states/counties).  The Census bureau [has an extremely detailed data dictionary](https://www2.census.gov/geo/pdfs/maps-data/data/tiger/tgrshp2019/TGRSHP2019_TechDoc.pdf), but it's not always apparent which Census-defined fields map to which fields in the `tiger` schema.  For example, my `tiger.state` table from postGIS has a `gid` field.  The Census tiger shapefiles do not have this, but they do have a `geoid` field that seems to be missing in my `tiger.state` table.  Are these the same field, with different names?

More generally, is there a way to figure out how the postGIS `tiger` schema is structured, and definitions for the various fields?

Comment: this might get you closer to the answer: [how to list schemas in postgresql](https://www.commandprompt.com/education/how-to-list-schemas-in-postgresql/#:~:text=In%20PostgreSQL%2C%20the%20standard%20%E2%80%9Cinformation_schema,like%20access%20privileges%20and%20description.) and [show tables](https://www.postgresqltutorial.com/postgresql-administration/postgresql-show-tables/#:~:text=Use%20the%20%5Cdt%20or%20%5Cdt%2B,from%20the%20pg_catalog.pg_tables%20catalog.)

Comment: @MikeD. yeah, I usually employ a GUI for exploratory db stuff such as DBeaver.  I can see the schema, the tables, and the columns, but there are no comments on any of them, and so it is not immediately clear what they all mean....

Comment: Found this gem in the generated script that loads the tiger data:  `ALTER TABLE tiger_staging.county RENAME geoid TO cntyidfp` I guess that explains the `geoid` field at least.